# Problema para pronosticar con regresión logística de statsmodels

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, predicción

soy nuevo en python y estoy tratando de generar una variable pronosticada. Estoy usando la base de Titanic. Ya eliminé los registros con valores nulos. Como dependiente uso `<strong>Survived</strong>` y como independiente estoy usando `<strong> Fare </strong>`.

El modelo lo puedo ejecutar sin problemas:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import logit<br>
X=titanic['Tarifa']<br>
y=titanic['Sobreviviente']<br>
modelo_s=sm.Logit(y,sm.add_constant(X))<br>
result=modelo_s.fit()<br>
print(result.summary())<br><br>
```

Cuando deseo pronosticar es cuando tengo el problema:

```
<br><br>
pred=modelo_s.predict(X)<br><br>
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-d3892381130a> in <module>
----> 1 pred=modelo_s.predict(X)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in predict(self, params, exog, linear)
    461             exog = self.exog
    462         if not linear:
--> 463             return self.cdf(np.dot(exog, params))
    464         else:
    465             return np.dot(exog, params)

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (712,2) and (712,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 712 (dim 0)
```

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Que son esos `<br>`?

Comment: Son para hacer saltos de línea.  En mi navegador se la línea contínua y lo añadí para cambiar de línea

Answer (score 0):

Al modelo le estás entrenando con la variable independiente que mencionas pero también le añades una columna de unos para el intercepto, y no la asignas nuevamente a los datos, es por esto que cuando predices, el tamaño de la entrada no es igual al que el modelo espera ( tamaño con el que ha sido entrenado ).

Una opción puede ser añadir acá la columna

```
pred=modelo_s.predict(sm.add_constant(X))
```

Otra opción es añadir el intercepto

```
X=titanic['Tarifa']

X=sm.add_constant(X)
```